# jQuery Validate not acting on custom validation value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

TLDR version: I have a custom jquery validation the returns the correct values but the rule is not getting enforced.

I have a custom validation rule that looks like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("isDomainValid", function(value, element) {
        var domain = value.split("@");
        $.get('/api/validate-domain/' + domain[1], function(data, status) {
            domain = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(domain['status'] === 'valid');
            return (domain['status'] === 'valid');
        });
    });
```

This validation calls a PHP API that checks if the email's domain name is live, hence correct. This API returns the correct values and the console.log() also reflects the correct values, which is the value I am returning as a boolean. All good so far...

I call this validation rule like this:

```
validator.validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            isDomainValid: true,
        },
});
```

I also have some custom error messages (I think maybe irrelevant) like the following:

```
messages: {
            email: {
                required: "The Email Address cannot be empty",
                isDomainValid: "Please correct the Email Address after the @ character",
                email: "Invalid Email Address format",
            }, },
```

All my validations, including one other custom validation work flawlessly except this one. Here is all the code I am running in case someone wants to see the whole thing. Again, all validations work except the custom isDomainValid validation.

```
    var validator = $('#checkout_form');
    
    $.validator.addMethod("checkPoBox", function(value, element) {
        let cleansedValue = $.trim(value.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '');
        let checked = $('#ship-box').prop('checked') ? true : false;
        if (/pobox/i.test(cleansedValue) && checked && element.name == 'shipping_address') {
            return false;
        }
        if (/pobox/i.test(cleansedValue) && !checked && element.name == 'billing_address') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    
    $.validator.addMethod("isDomainValid", function(value, element) {
        var domain = value.split("@");
        $.get('/api/validate-domain/' + domain[1], function(data, status) {
            domain = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(domain['status'] === 'valid');
            return (domain['status'] === 'valid');
        });
    });
    
    validator.validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                isDomainValid: true,
            },
            billing_first_name: {
                required: true
            },
            billing_last_name: {
                required: true
            },
            billing_address: {
                required: true,
                checkPoBox: true
            },
            billing_city: {
                required: true
            },
            billing_state: {
                required: true
            },
            billing_zip: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 5,
                digits: true
            },
            billing_phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10,
                digits: true
            },
            name_on_credit_card: {
                required: true
            },
            credit_card_number: {
                required: true,
                creditcard: true
            },
            expiration_month: {
                required: true
            },
            expiration_year: {
                required: true
            },
            cvv: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 4,
                digits: true
            },
            shipping_first_name: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                }
            },
            shipping_last_name: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                }
            },
            shipping_address: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                },
                checkPoBox: true
            },
            shipping_city: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                }
            },
            shipping_state: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                }
            },
            shipping_zip: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                },
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 5,
                digits: true
            },
            shipping_phone: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('#ship-box').prop('checked');
                },
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10,
                digits: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "The Email Address cannot be empty",
                isDomainValid: "Please correct the Email Address after the @ character",
                email: "Invalid Email Address format",
            },
            billing_first_name: "First Name cannot be blank",
            billing_last_name: "Last Name cannot be blank",
            billing_address: {
                required: "Address cannot be blank",
                checkPoBox: "Products cannot be shipped to a P.O. Box"
            },
            billing_city: "Town/City cannot be blank",
            billing_state: "Please select a State",
            billing_zip: "Please enter a valid 5 digit Zip Code",
            billing_phone: "Please enter a valid 10 digit Phone Number",
            name_on_credit_card: "Name on Card cannot be blank",
            credit_card_number: "Please enter a valid Credit Car Number",
            expiration_month: "Please select an Expiration Month",
            expiration_year: "Please select an Expiration Year",
            cvv: "Please enter a valid 3 or 4 digit CVV",
            shipping_first_name: "First Name cannot be blank",
            shipping_last_name: "Last Name cannot be blank",
            shipping_address: {
                required: "Address cannot be blank",
                checkPoBox: "Products cannot be shipped to a P.O. Box"
            },
            shipping_city: "City cannot be blank",
            shipping_state: "Please select a State",
            shipping_zip: "Please enter a valid 5 digit Zip Code",
            shipping_phone: "Please enter a valid 10 digit Phone Number",
        },
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
            if(validator.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('button#place_order_btn').text("PLACE ORDER");
                return false;
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (validator) {
            validator.submit();
        }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into a problem where the return value for the success callback function is lost in the `$.get` method. In my experience I've had to trigger errors manually as part of the callback when checking against the server in a similar way.

Alternatively, I was digging around and found some jQuery Validation documentation that seems like it would make what you are trying to do a little easier: https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Try updating the `rules.email` properties, replacing `isDomainValid`:

```js
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: function() {
          var value = $("[name='email']").val();
          var domain = value.split("@");
          return "/api/validate-domain/" + domain[1];
        },
      }
    },
```

You can remove the call to `$.validator.addMethod` that registers the "isDomainValid" method.

Also, don't forget to update `isDomainValid` elsewhere, replacing it with `remote` so the messages are correct.

```js
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "The Email Address cannot be empty",
      email: "Invalid Email Address format",
      remote: "Please correct the Email Address after the @ character",
    },
```